# Refreshing line reading operator Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, filestream

what happens after the eof is reached with <> operator in perl?

I'm reading INP1 line by line with

```
while(<INP1>) {
}
```

but I need to do this reading multiple times and I need to start from the beginning of the file each time. How can I do that? Is there something like refreshing the stream in perl?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `INP1` is connected to a regular filehandle (not a socket handle or pipe handle), you can also [`seek`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#seek) back to the beginning of the file.

```
while(<INP1>) {
   ...
}
seek INP1, 0, 0;

# do it again
while (<INP1>) {
   ...
}
```

Another option is to load the entire file into an array one time, and then loop through that array as often as you wish. This is a good idea if the whole file fits comfortably in memory and if the contents of the file won't change between traversals.

```
open INP1, '<', $the_file;
@INP1 = <INP1>;
close INP1;

foreach (@INP1) {
   ...
}

# do it again
foreach (@INP1) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: use lexically scoped filehandles

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) to go back to the start of the file, you could use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie%3a%3aFile) to treat the file as an array of lines. Depending on your access pattern, this might be more efficient than re-reading the file from the start each and every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can `seek` back to the beginning:

```
use Fcntl;
open INP1, ...
while (<INP1>) {
}
seek INP1, 0, SEEK_SET;
while (<INP1>) {
}
```

This will only work properly if INP1 is a real file (not a pipe or socket).

Comment: I sure hope this program start with `use strict`, `use warnings qw<FATAL all>`, `use autodie`, one or another flavor of `use open qw< :std IO :utf8 >`, `END{close STDOUT}`, and an explicit `close INP1`. Like, you know? :(

Comment: @tchrist: Good suggestions, but they don't address the question the OP asked so I consider them off-topic and won't include them in my answer.

Comment: @Adrian: Making syscalls without checking their success is acceptable under what circumstances?

Comment: @tchrist => I think part of the problem might be that most of the perldocs never explicitly check for errors, which probably keeps that from sticking as well as it could.  I just spent a minute googling the docs, and the only example of seek with an error check that I saw was in one of your tutorials :)

Comment: @Eric: Agreed, but I'm not convinced that's a bad thing. Examples are provided to illustrate a point; error checking creates a distraction. If an example is about using a filehandle any appearance of `open` is secondary; error checking is tertiary noise. Additionally, the appropriate error response is application-dependent, so cargo-culting error checking isn't right, either (though it could lead to better code on average). Finally, "best practice" changes. e.g. even if the docs had `open or die` some would want it changed to `use autodie`.

Comment: @Adrian - tell all the haters to `autodie and goto &hell`